# How can I add toppings to a p5.js pizza slice randomly based on size and avoid looping when adding more toppings?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, random, p5.js

I am creating a pizza in p5.js, and want to add toppings. The toppings I want to add, I want placed randomly on the pizza slice, but I have 3 different pizza sizes, small, medium, and large. I want the toppings to match with the pizza size, as in if the pizza size is small, then I won't have toppings going over the edge of the pizza circle. I was using a `for() loop`, and `random()` to get desired area of the toppings. When I click `checkbox1`, the color and rectangles appear, but they seem to be looping over and over again. I don't want the toppings to loop over and over, and I want to put more toppings over top of it. What should I do to stop it from looping?

Html:

```
<div id="sizeContainer" class="radio-container">Pick a size!<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="one" id="button1" onchange="checkS()" />
        <label for="button1">Small</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="two" id="button2" onchange="checkM()" />
        <label for="button2">Medium</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="three" id="button3" onchange="checkL()" />
        <label for="button3">Large</label><br>
        </div>
        <div id="toppingContainer" class="checkbox-container">Choose some toppings!
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="oneC" id="checkbox1"/>
            <label for="checkbox1">Pepperoni</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="twoC" id="checkbox2"/>
            <label for="checkbox2">Cheese</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="threeC" id="checkbox3"/>
            <label for="checkbox3">Musrooms</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="fourC" id="checkbox4"/>
            <label for="checkbox4">Olives</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="fiveC" id="checkbox5"/>
            <label for="checkbox5">Pineapple</label>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
let checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
let checkbox2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
let checkbox3 = document.getElementById("checkbox3");
let checkbox4 = document.getElementById("checkbox4");
let checkbox5 = document.getElementById("checkbox5");

function draw() {
  background(175, 40, 33);
  if (button1.checked) {
    fill(227,217,202);
    circle(200,200,100);
  }

  if (button2.checked) {
    fill(227,217,202);
    circle(200,200,200);
  }
  
  if (button3.checked){
    fill(227,217,202);
    circle(200,200,300);
  }
  
  if (checkbox1.checked){
    fill("green");
  }

  if(checkbox2.checked){
    fill("purple");
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
    push();
    randAng = random(0, 2 * PI);
    distFromCenter = random(0, 40);
    offsetX = distFromCenter * cos(randAng);
    offsetY = distFromCenter * sin(randAng);
    x = 200 + offsetX;
    y = 200 + offsetY;
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(random(0, 2 * PI));
    strokeWeight(0);
    rect(0, 0, 4, 4);
    pop();
  }

}

function checkS() {
  button1.checked;
}

function checkM() {
  button2.checked;
}

function checkL(){
  button3.checked;
}

function setup() {
  myCanvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
}
```

Thank you.